# В чем преимущество Yii2 перед уже готовыми CMS?

Tags: php, html, yii, yii2, веб-программирование

В чем преимущество Yii2 перед уже готовыми CMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В том же, в чём преимущество перед готовой CMS любого фреймворка.

**Готовая CMS:**

- Как правило, ориентирована на решение чётко определённого круга задач;
- Система представляет собой полностью законченное решение. Изменение возможно только путём расширения уже имеющегося функционала. Для открытых CMS ещё есть возможность переписать ядро "под себя". Но, тогда сразу прощай обновления от разработчиков и т.д.;
- Часто содержат "лишний" функционал, который не используется в работе.

**Фреймворк:**

- Можно написать собственную CMS полностью адаптированную под нужные задачи;
- Не требуется писать код с чистого листа. Фреймворк уже содержит базовый набор компонентов, из которых можно как из "кирпичей" построить собственную реализацию;
- Если выбор фреймворка и реализация грамотно продуманы, в готовом решении не будет ничего "лишнего".

Comment: Streletz- Получается что сейчас актуально использовать уже готовые CMS  вместо того что бы писать свои? Зачем писать свои так как уже готовые есть?

Comment: @Niko_D А зачем делают новые авто, если уже готовые есть?

Comment: @Niko_D - новые авто - это прогресс, они более функциональнее, чем их предшественники. И все-таки не совсем понятно, почему для чего конкретно нужны движки типа yyi2.  Понятно, если делать какой то эксклюзивный проект , то да. Но в основном сайты делятся на четыре типа : 1 Лединг 2.Визитка. 4.Корпоративный. 5.Интернет магазин. И по моему CMS полностью может обеспечить потребность для этих классов сайтов , которые я привел. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @Niko_D Если клепать шаблонные однотипные сайты со стандартным  типичным функционалом - то можно пользоваться `cms`...А если что-то нестандартное нужно, своеобразное, частично отличное по-функционалу? К тому же `cms` преобладают чрезмерно перегруженным функционалом, порой 70% которого не используется и только имеют лишний вес и тормозят всю систему. на визитку я бы не стал вешать `cms`. Это все равно что делать велосипед из трактора беларусь....а фреймворк - это по сути колесо,руль,рама, цепь - из которых можно построить нужный определенный легкий велосипед.

Answer (score 1):

Это вообще разные вещи. CMS - готовая система управления контентом (готовая система предоставляющая конкретный функционал), а фреймворки (не только yii) это каркас+библиотеки (инструментарий) для создания чего-либо, в том числе и CMS.

Comment: vitidev - А зачем изобретать велосипед если он уже придуман?

Comment: @Niko_D Бизнес-процессы у каждого свои, а велосипед вынуждает подстраиваться под него или же пытаться настроить велосипед под свои нужды, что бывает нелегко. Это правило такое -  чем более общие задачи призвана решать система, тем меньше она позволяет решать конкретные задачи. И дорабатывая/настраивая ее в какой-то момент написать заточенный под проблему продукт становится дешевле. Поэтому программисты так востребованы, хотя вроде бы "все уже давно написано, бери да используй".